# EntityFramework 6 Code-based configuration of connection string for database-first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm attempting to make an existing application work without an app.config (it is required due to a very specific environment). Problem is that it's heavily relying on EntityFramework 6 to work with an SQL-Server.

I'm trying to use a [code-based configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx), but I can't figure out how to provide a correct connection string through my configuration class.

I made a configuration class:

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new MyConnectionFactory());
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient", System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance);
    }
}
```

Then provided it to my DbContext (Generated by EF automatically from bd):

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyConfiguration))]
public partial class TestModelEntities
{           
}
```

With a custom connection factory:

```
public class MyConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        var newConnStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            UserID = "user",
            Password = "pass",
            InitialCatalog = "databaseName",
            DataSource = "serverName"
        };

        var entityConnectionBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
            ProviderConnectionString = newConnStringBuilder.ToString(),
            Metadata = @"res://*/TestModel.csdl|
                            res://*/TestModel.ssdl|
                            res://*/TestModel.msl"
        };

        var newDbConnect = new EntityConnection(entityConnectionBuilder.ToString());
        return newDbConnect;
    }
}
```

However. When I test it, I get an `UnintentionalCodeFirstException`. Why? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should provide connection string to your context via *:base(connectionString)*. Create a class as below:

```
public class ConnectionStringBuilder
{
    public static string Construct()
    {
        var newConnStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            UserID = "user",
            Password = "pass",
            InitialCatalog = "databaseName",
            DataSource = "serverName"
        };

        var entityConnectionBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
            ProviderConnectionString = newConnStringBuilder.ToString(),
            Metadata = @"res://*/TestModel.csdl|
                            res://*/TestModel.ssdl|
                            res://*/TestModel.msl"
        };

        return entityConnectionBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then modify your Context constructor to look like this:

```
public DbContext()
    : base(ConnectionStringBuilder.Construct())
{
}
```

It should work fine now. ([source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a159280f-700e-4f48-82bd-0e7a2944c01e/can-ms-confirm-its-not-possible-to-pass-in-connection-string-to-ef-in-dbfirst?forum=adodotnetentityframework&prof=required))

Comment: Heh. Surprisingly simple solution. Thanks!